# Table or lists for forum threads

Tags: html, semantics, markup

I'm wondering which would be more semantic when writing the markup for a list of recently active forum threads: A table, some kind of definition list, or a mixture of both?

To give you an example of what I mean:
[image: Screenshot of forum thread list]

I'm thinking that the best way would be to let each thread be an unordered list item containing a defintion list that contains the thread title, number of posts, etc. But I wanted to get other people's input as well, because I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Honestly? I'm not convinced that it's **not** tabular data. I'd probably recommend sticking with the `table` element in this particular case.

Comment: I'm not sure about what is semantically correct, but phpBB3 uses `li`s and `ld`s, if that is what you are trying to emulate.

Comment: @Saladin Akara: Not trying to emulate it. It was just an example to show you what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly tabular data, and belongs in a `<table>` element - for semantical as well as practical reasons.

The direct page links in the second column might be a good fit for a `ol` element .

There is a very interesting discussion on the general question of when table elements are applicable here: [Proper definition for "tabular data" in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134881/proper-definition-for-tabular-data-in-html)