# 2011: DIVs OR TABLEs? Are Div/Input/Labels still the way to go, or are XHTML Tables (tables/tr/td) back in style?

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml

DIVs or TABLEs?

**Here's a question for front-end developers out there. Are table-less designs still required by most projects you work, or are simple tables structures accepted again? If so, were are tables appropriate? Data? Forms?**

I recall, not more than a couple years ago, a designer friend of mine told me that I had to go table-less with all my HTML/XHTML. Everrrything tables. That DIV's were the way to go. Being more of a backend PHP/MySQL developer I tried to jump on the band-wagon with a CakePHP project or two. I revamped most of the basic template pages/structures to use DIV's with CSS2.

Now that I'm doing more CodeIgniter work... well, I'm now using tables with most of my Forms. I've had some issue with Divs. Tables are so much more structured and present me with less issues (IE6). Is this considered "bad code"? The company I'm working for has an image to withhold.

Thanks, Jeff

Edit: Please don't downgrade the question. It's a legitimate question from a non-designer needing to do front-end work. Maybe I should have asked , "Where is it appropriate to use tables in XHTML/CSS2?"

Comment: I am all for "judicial use of tables" even for "non-tabular data". However, the keyword is *judicial* (as in discriminating) -- that is, *please don't* make your site like SharePoint 2007 and before :-)

Comment: it seems like more of the jquery and javascript plugins these days trend towards lists rather than tables, so thats the way i'd go.

Comment: The way I decide is usually if the number of columns is > 3 I go with html table, for 2, max 3 columns divs work just fine for me. There is nothing really wrong with using tables especially for business type websites where you need to see data in a spreadsheet-like view.

Comment: I don't know whether or not to close this question. The OP is asking for an opinionated answer but the correct one is decisively based on semantics, not the 'popular' choice for the year.

Comment: You know the answer to this as soon as you inherit a table-based layout that you need to redesign... all the work is now spread across a million template and html files rather than a single CSS file. GLHF.

Comment: Question shouldn't have been closed IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a designer friend of mine told me that I had to go table-less with all my HTML/XHTML.

Tables have one defined purpose: **Tabular data.** For that purpose, using them was *never* wrong. Using divs or other elements to re-build a table for tabular data is, was, and always has been a fine example of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) - adopting something ("Eeeek, tables are evil!") without really understanding why.

See this SO question for attempted definitions of what constitutes tabular data:  [Proper definition for "tabular data" in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134881/proper-definition-for-tabular-data-in-html)

What they should *not* be used for is **layouting the page**. That has really come out of style, and will probably never get back in style any more, seeing as they become less and less necessary as CSS improves.

I personally find using tables for forms totally okay, by the way.

Comment: @Widor thanks, but that honour isn't mine :) see e.g. http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Font_rendering_and_text_layouting

Comment: Crikey! Ah well, you can keep the 10 rep, you look like you need it!

Comment: @Widor thank you Sir! I'm saving up rep for my own Q&A site.

Comment: How selfish! I assumed you were going to be a StackOverflow philanthropist and blow it all on offering a super-bounty!

Comment: Yes, that's the plan - I will put huge bounties on terrible, terrible questions and answers, thus disrupting the SO economy so badly that it crashes, and everyone has to move on to *my* Q&A site. After successfully destroying SO, I might hire either Jeff or Joel as assistant moderators. But not both - I wouldn't want to spend too much on staff, would I? *Cackle*